# DHCP allocating 2 different IPs to same box with two network ports but same name?

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp

Is there any way to tell DHCP or DNS to name IPs on the same box different.

I have a win2k DHCP server that is correctly allocating different IPs to two network cards on the same Win2003 box. So I get

10.0.0.128             Solve50

10.0.0.129             Solve50

Pinging Solve50 will always return 10.0.0.128.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DHCP allocated addresses are assigned and registered with DNS on a per adapter basis, not a per machine basis. You'll need to modify the properties of the adapters to alter this behavior.

You can disable the "Register this conection's adresses in DNS" option on the adapter that you don't want registered with DNS or, if you want them both registered but with different names then set those options in the Advanced DNS properties of TCP/IP on each NIC.